# How to implement a linear and a logistic regression in a single SEM model using R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, structural-equation-modeling

I created a SEM model in R (lavaan package), but one of my dependent variables is continuous, while the other is binary.

The model is as follows:

```
modelx <- '
a =~ a1 + a2 + a3

b =~ b1 + b2 + b3

c =~ c1 + c2 + c3

x ~ a + b + c + z + w

y ~ a + b + c + z + w

'

sem(modelx, data=mydata, estimator="DWLS")
```

z and w are covariates. x is a scale (0-12), however y is a binary variable (0;1).

Thus, the question is, how can I implement a linear regression for predicting x and a logistic regression for y in a single SEM model? I assume that lavaan doesn't automatically account for the different dependent variables. If it does, I would like to see a reference for that. All ideas are welcome.

Edit: Using the latent variable factor scores from the measurement model for a, b, c in a glm (binomial reg for y and linear for x) and lavaan, the results are more closely aligned for x than for y. Does it mean that lavaan ignores/doesn't do good with the dichotomous variable in this particular case, or my question from the start is moot or unnecessary?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. What is a single SEM model? Just try it. Compare y ~ x, where x is binary, in glm-logistic and lavaan.

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for pointing that out. I should edit the question to make it more clear. The results from a glm and lavaan differ, hence my confusion. Using the latent variable factor scores from the measurement model for a, b, c in a glm (binomial reg on y) and lavaan show differing results (some regressions in the latter gain significance). On the other hand, using the same factor scores in a linear regression for x had much more closely aligned results when compared to lavaan. Thus, I was thinking that lavaan accommodates more for the latter.

Comment: Yes, Lavaan does.